# Electron - Showing Menu on only Main Window

Tags: javascript, electron

I am new to writing in Electron on windows. When I create a `menuTemplate` this is showing on all of my windows that are opened. Is there a way to only have the menu appear on my `mainWindow`? (Not on the pop up windows I create)

**Index.js**

```
const electron = require('electron');

const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = electron;

let mainWindow;
let addWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/main.html`);
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => app.quit());

  const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
});

function createAddWindow() {
  addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    title: 'Add New Todo'
  });
  addWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/add.html`)
}

const menuTemplate = [
  {
    label: 'File',
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'New Todo' ,
        click() { createAddWindow(); }
      },
      {
        label: 'Quit',
        accelerator: process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'Command+Q' : 'Ctrl+Q',
        click() {
          app.quit();
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
  menuTemplate.unshift({});
}
```

Comment: You can use `CommandOrControl+Q` or `CmdOrCtrl+Q` instead of `process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'Command+Q' : 'Ctrl+Q'`. See [Accelerator](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/accelerator.md)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);` to `mainWindow.setMenu(mainMenu)`.

The `Menu.setApplicationMenu` sets the Menu for **all** BrowserWindows, while `win.setMenu` sets it only for the window it is called on.

Comment: hmmm then every new window gets defaulted back to the default menu bar? Is there an easy way to make all new windows not use that default bar then?

Comment: Use `Menu.setApplicationMenu(null)` to disable the default Menu (Mac will still have the menu at the very top). Then set the menu as usual with `mainWindow.setMenu(mainMenu)` for your mainWindow.